# How are Cold Streams able to work properly in a concurrent environment, while obeying "Item 79" in "Effective Java"?

Tags: stream, reactive-programming, deadlock, publish-subscribe, synchronized

## In summary:

The *cascade effect* nature of the Cold Stream, from Inactive to Active, Is in itself an "alien" execution (alien to the reactive design) that MUST BE EXECUTED WITHIN THE SYNCRHONIZED REGION, and this is unavoidable, going against Item 79 of Effective Java.

---

Effective Java: Item 79:

> "..., to avoid deadlock and data corruption, **never call an alien
> method from within a synchronized region**. More generally, keep the
> amount of work that you do from within synchronized to a minimum."

**never call an alien
method from within a synchronized region**

An `add(Consumer<T> observer)` AND `remove(Consumer<T> observer)` WILL BE concurrent (because of switchMaps that react to asynchronous changes in values/states), BUT according to Item 79, it should not be possible for a subscribe(Publisher p); method to even exist.

Since a subscribe(publisher) MUST WORK as a callback function that reacts to additions and removals of observers...

```
private final Object lock = new Object();
private volatile BooleanConsumer suscriptor;

public void subscribe(Publisher p) {
    syncrhonized (lock) {
        suscriptor = isActive -> {
            if (isActive) p.add(this);
            else p.remove(this);
        }
    }
}

public void add(Consumer<T> observer) {
    syncrhonized (lock) {
        observers.add(observer);
        if (observer.size() > 0) suscriptor.accept(true);
    }
}
```

I would argue that using a volatile mediator is better than holding on to the Publisher directly, but holding on to the publisher makes no difference at all, because by altering its state (when adding ourselves to the publisher) we are triggering the functions (other possible subscriptions to publishers) within it!!!, There really is no difference.

Doing it via misdirection is the proper answer, and doing so is the main idea behind the separation of concerns principle!!

Instead, what Item 79 is asking, is that each time an observer is added, we manually synchronize FROM THE OUT/ALIEN-SIDE, and deliberately check whether a subscription must be performed.

```
synchronized (alienLock) {
    observable.add(observer);
    if (observable.getObserverSize() > 0) {
        publishier.add(observable);
    }
}
```

and each time an observer is removed:

```
synchronized (alienLock) {
    observable.remove(observer);
    if (observable.getObserverSize() == 0) {
        publishier.remove(observable);
    }
}
```

Imagine those lines repeated EACH and EVERY TIME a node forks or joins on to a new one (in the reactive graph), it would be an insane amount of boilerplate defeating the entire purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Reading carefully the item, you can see that the rule is there to prevent a "something" done wrong by the user that hangs the thread preventing accesses.

And this answer will be part me trying to justify why this is possible but also a non-issue in this case.

1. Binary Events.

In this case an event that involves only 2 states, isActive == true || false;

This means that if the consumption gets "hanged" on true, the only other option that may be waiting is "false", BUT even worst...

IF one of the two becomes deadlocked, it means the entire system is deadlocked anyways... in reality the issue is outside the design, not inside.

What I mean is that out of the 2 possible options: true or false. the time it takes for either of them to execute is meaningless since the ONLY OTHER OPTION IS STILL REQUIRED TO WAIT regardless.

2. Enclosed functionality of the lock.

Even if subscribe(Publisher p) methods can be concatenated, the only thing the user has access to, IS NOT THE lock per se, but the method.

So even If we are executing "alien methods" with functions, inside our synchronized bodies, THOSE FUNCTIONS ARE STILL OURS, and we know what they have inside them and how they work and what exactly they will perform.

In this case **the only uncertainty** in the system is not what the functions will do, but **HOW MANY CONTATENATIONS THE SYSTEM HAS**.

3. What's wrong in my code:

Finally, the only thing (I see) wrong, is that observers and subscriptions MOST DEFINITEY WORK IN SEPARATE LOCKS, because observers MUST NOT, under any circumstance should allow themselves to get locked while a subscription domino effect is taking place.

I believe that's all...